# Encoding UTF-32 corrupts smaller byte size base64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64

I have a strange scenario where if the base64 `string` length is in certain `Bytes` size e.g. 1100 then encoding to `UTF-32` fails?

However if I use encoding `UTF-8` then it does the conversion fine.

I have to use `UTF-32` as I can be dealing with larger string payload size of upto 12000 bytes.

This is the static method I use to do the conversion.

```
public static string DecodeBase64ToString(string value)
{
    return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value));
}
```

I am not really sure as to why it would corrupt the payload? When I say corrupt it should convert it to JSON but the output looks more like `/000000/111111/`

Any suggestions guys? Sorry can't share the base64 string value as it's sensitive data.

Comment: UTF32 is *not* a suitable encoding if your input is an *arbitrary* set of bytes and the expected output is a string. Conversely, Base64 *is* a suitable encoding from *arbitrary* bytes to a string. It's unclear why you think Base64 isn't suitable but trying to use UTF32 for a purpose it's not intended for isn't the solution.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not sure if I understand fully what you've said? Basically original payload is encoded base64 string. I need to convert it from base64 to readable string value.

Comment: The encoding to create the base64 string has to be the same as the encoding used after the conversion.  If you took at string that was three bytes and converted to a Base64 string you cannot convert it back to bytes and then use 32 bit encoding.

Comment: @jdweng understood much clearer now. So is there a way to figure out which encoding is used for a Base64 string?

Comment: You are sending/receiving data and there is an implied protocol.  In this case the protocol has to include the encoding.